# Temporarily remove toJSON fn member of object

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, local-storage, parse-platform

I'm trying to store variables in localStorage on my mobile website so if the user leaves, their state is not lost. In order to do that I store all important data as JSON in localStorage. However, some parts of the data are Parse objects (Backbone models) and have a `toJSON` function. In order to unobtrusively store the data, I need to remove the `toJSON` so that the object is stored as-is, and then re-attach it. However, my code isn't working:

```
                var toJSON = null;
                if(obj && obj.toJSON) {
                    toJSON = obj.toJSON;
                    delete obj.toJSON;
                }

                window.localStorage[localStorageIndex] = JSON.stringify(obj);

                if(toJSON)
                    obj.toJSON = toJSON;
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `toJSON` is a method of your object and not simply an object prototype's method? That's really weird, object prototype's properties shouldn't be stringified.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be the object's prototype's method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned not to store heavy objects using localStorage...

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
obj.toJSON = undefined;

window.localStorage[localStorageIndex] = JSON.stringify(obj);

delete obj.toJSON;
```

This should temporarily shadow the prototyped `toJSON` with `undefined`, causing `stringify()` to skip over it.

Comment: It fails with a `undefined is not a function` error. I've also tried setting toJSON to an empty function, `function() {}` but that fails too. I've decided that stringifying and parsing objects is inefficient and impractical so I'm going to store pointers to the data that I need instead.